# Bash detect characters that don't have corresponding var

Tags: bash, variables, space

I have done a script which define a variable for each letters (for an encryption process), but I want spaces to be in the ouput.

I have this :

```
eiput_splitted="$(echo $einput | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')"
export eouput=""

for input in $eiput_splitted; do
    export eouput=$eouput${!input}
    //added code here
done
```

but I don't know how to detect spaces in the loop.
I tried

```
if [ $input = \  ]
if [ $input = *\ * ]
if [ $input = *"\ "* ]
if [ $input = "*\ *" ]
if [ -z ${!input+x} ] (to detect unset variables, but doesn't seem to work..)
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in BASH:

```
while IFS= read -r ch; do 
    [[ "$ch" == " " ]] && echo "space character"
done < <(grep -o . <<< "$einput")
```

- `grep -o . <<< "$einput"` to split input string character by character
- `< <(...)` is called process substitution
- `IFS=` to set input field separator to null (to allow space to be read by `read)

Comment: Okay. I understand mos of your code, but not all of it. What is "read -r ch" ? (I am sorry, I'm a beginner...). Also, is placing x < < y the same as y | x ?

Comment: Yes `< <(...)` is same piped command but is more efficient than using pipes. `<<<` is called herestring in BASH and `IFS= read -r` reads a full line from input (which is `grep` command's output).

Comment: Thanks ! You saved me a bunch of time !

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't quote the string, any whitespace in it will be lost. Try this instead.

```
echo "$einput" |
sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' |
while IFS= read -r input; do
    eouput="$eouput${!input}"
    :
done
```

Depending on what your further processing looks like, I would perhaps just `printf '%s' "${!input}"` inside the loop, and process its output in a pipeline after `done` if necessary, to avoid yet another variable.

Comment: This is about halfway between your original and @anubhava's major refactoring. It avoids the pesky temporary variable and uses quoting everywhere, and `IFS= read -r` to read every input token literally.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is not very good. You should not use plain variables like so! You'll run into problems if you want to encode special characters like `_`, `*`, `é`, etc.

Instead, you should use associative arrays. Here's a full pure Bash working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read message to encode on stdin and outputs message to stdout

declare -A lookup

lookup=(
   [a]=n [b]=o [c]=p [d]=q [e]=r [f]=s [g]=t [h]=u [i]=v [j]=w [k]=x
   [l]=y [m]=z [n]=a [o]=b [p]=c [q]=d [r]=e [s]=f [t]=g [u]=h [v]=i
   [w]=j [x]=k [y]=l [z]=m
)

while IFS= read -r -d '' -n 1 char; do
   if [[ -z $char ]]; then
      # null byte
      printf '\0'
   elif [[ ${lookup["$char"]} ]]; then
      # defined character
      printf '%s' "${lookup["$char"]}"
   elif [[ $char = @(' '|$'\n') ]]; then
      # space and newline
      printf '%s' "$char"
   else
      # other characters passed verbatim with warning message
      printf >&2 "Warning, character \`%s' not supported\n" "$char"
      printf '%s' "$char"
   fi
done
```

I called this script `banana`, `chmod +x banana` and:

```
$ ./banana <<< "hello stackoverflow"
uryyb fgnpxbiresybj
$ ./banana <<< "uryyb fgnpxbiresybj"
hello stackoverflow
```

If you want to encode the content of the variable `input` and store the encoded text in the variable `output`, just modify the main loop as so:

```
output=
linput=$input
while [[ $linput ]]; do
   char=${linput::1}
   linput=${linput:1}
   if [[ ${lookup["$char"]} ]]; then
      # defined character
      output+=${lookup["$char"]}
   elif [[ $char = @(' '|$'\n') ]]; then
      # space and newline
      output+=$char
   else
      # other characters passed verbatim with warning message
      printf >&2 "Warning, character \`%s' not supported\n" "$char"
      output+=$char
   fi
done
```

In this case, I omitted the check for the null byte, as a Bash variable can't contain the null byte.

---

Proceeding like so, you can really encode any character you like (even null bytes—in the first version—and newline characters).

---

Edit (re your comment).

You want to use this for a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) script. Your concern is that you prompt the user for the number used for the shift and you don't know how to use this method in your case. The key is that it's rather easy to generate the lookup table.

Here's a fully working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

chrv() {
   local c
   printf -v c '\\%03o' "$1"
   printf -v "$2" "$c"
}

ansi_normal=$'\E[0m'
ansi_lightgreen=$'\E[02m'

while true; do
   printf '%s' "Encryption key (number from ${ansi_lightgreen}1$ansi_normal to ${ansi_lightgreen}26$ansi_normal): "
   read -re ekey
   if [[ $ekey = +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
      ((ekey=10#$ekey))
      ((ekey>=1 && ekey<=26)) && break
   fi
   printf 'Bad number. Try again.\n'
done

# Build the lookup table according to this number
declare -A lookup

for i in {0..25}; do
   for u in 65 97; do
      chrv "$((i+u))" basechar
      chrv "$(((i+ekey-1)%26+u))" "lookup["$basechar"]"
   done
done

printf '%s' "Input (only ${ansi_lightgreen}letters$ansi_normal and ${ansi_lightgreen}spaces${ansi_normal}): "
IFS= read -re einput
read -n1 -rep "Do you want output to be uppercase? ${ansi_lightgreen}(y/n)$ansi_normal " oup
[[ ${oup,,} = y ]] && einput=${einput^^}

output=
linput=$einput
while [[ $linput ]]; do
   char=${linput::1}
   linput=${linput:1}
   if [[ ${lookup["$char"]} ]]; then
      # defined character
      output+=${lookup["$char"]}
   elif [[ $char = @(' '|$'\n') ]]; then
      # space and newline
      output+=$char
   else
      # other characters passed verbatim with warning message
      printf >&2 "Warning, character \`%s' not supported\n" "$char"
      output+=$char
   fi
done

printf 'Original text: %s\n' "$einput"
printf 'Encoded text: %s\n' "$output"
```

Pure Bash and no subshells `:)`.

Comment: Hey. First of all, thank you for taking time to answer me. The thing is that each letters has a corresponding other, but it is prompted by the script (with an encryption key, it's a caesar cipher script).

Comment: @FliiFe No problem: you just need to build the `lookup` table instead of hard-coding it. It would be interesting that you showed us how you prompt and build your variables. Very likely you adopted a poor design and broken methods (and I'll explain you why it's broken and how to fix all that). By the way I hope you recognized the rot13 encoding there `:)`.

Comment: Okay. please have a look at this : https://bitbucket.org/FliiFe/scripts/src/691010b7ee7e757bfba3d1bf553c7b08e52c12dc/Caesar_cipher?at=master . Can you contact me by Private message ?

Comment: @FliiFe sorry, I can't contact you privately (my wage wouldn't be affordable `:D`). I edited my answer to include a fully working example, (loosely) based on your current script.

Comment: @gniourf_gniouf Thanks a bunch. I'll not take your code untill I don't understand it completly, but I'll work on it. Thanks. Thanks. Thanks.

Comment: @FliiFe if you have any questions, please ask for clarification! good luck.

Comment: What do `chrv()` do ?

Comment: @FliiFe `chrv` takes two arguments. The first one is a number (the codepoint of a character, e.g., it's `97` for `a`) and the second one is the variable name where to store the character. For example, calling `chrv 97 foo` will store the character `a` into variable `foo`. We're using this function to build the lookup table.

Comment: Oh. That's so clever! Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand line 15 to 18... Can you explain me please ?

Comment: @FliiFe This is to validate user input: `[[ $ekey = +([[:digit:]]) ]]` is true if and only if `ekey` is a string of one or more digits (just to make sure user input a string of digits).  `((ekey=10#$ekey))` makes sure Bash understands it in radix 10. Without this, a value of, e.g., `08` or `09` would make Bash complain, as (without radix 10 specified by `10#`), when there's a leading 0, Bash understands the number in radix 8. `((ekey>=1 && ekey<=26)) && break` makes sure the number is in the range [1,26].

Answer (score 0):

change the internal field seperator from spaces to newlines using `IFS=$'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the characters of a string, you can use parameter expansion:

```
eiput='Hello World!'
H="capital letter 'h'"
l="I appear 3 times"

strlen=${#eiput}
for ((i=0; i<strlen; i++)); do
    char=${eiput:i:1}
    printf "%2d:%c:%s\n" $i "$char" "${!char}"
done
```

```
 0:H:capital letter 'h'
 1:e:
 2:l:I appear 3 times
 3:l:I appear 3 times
 4:o:
 5: :
 6:W:
 7:o:
 8:r:
 9:l:I appear 3 times
10:d:
11:!:
```